# How do i configure the live usb to install additional packages?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, live-usb, downloads

I have saved all the packages from the directory `/var/cat/apt/archives` to Usb.

Is it possible to configure the live Usb to accommodate all these extra  packages `/var/cache/apt/archives`; so that it installs all of them during the fresh install / reinstall process.

I don't want to install each of the downloaded package manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this by using software like Ubuntu Builder (This is only one way be sure to explore others)

**Ubuntu Builder** allows you to create your own Ubuntu based distribution in clicks. You are free to choose your own desktop environment, window manager, **packages etc**, and customize Ubuntu the way you want. You can download the latest .deb files [here](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/downloads/list).

[image]

Be sure to do more research and return here if you have any additional questions

Comment: @Exeleration-G  Saw the link you added.  I am happy to keep it there but my answer wasn’t to advocate Ubuntu Builder.  It was to suggest to the OP to use something like Ubuntu Builder (being one option).  Thanks

Comment: Well, I just guessed that I could spare the AU'ers a Google search :-D

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have the Live USB install them automatically.

However once the installation is complete, you can open the USB in the terminal, go to the directory with the backed up files, and type the below to install them all:

```
sudo dpkg --install *.deb
```