# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a persistent bootable USB stick WITH installed packages

Tags: live-usb

My question is if is it possible to install a customized LiveUSB (Ubuntu with some extra packages installed) into a PC with those changes.
Meaning if i install restricted packages in my usb I can guarantee those files to be installed into the pc as well.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Never done it, but in principle you would "create" a new distro, that is, the basic Ubuntu with some additions and, perhaps, some things removed.

That would get you an ISO file, which you then use for the LiveUSB.

Check, for example:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto#Tools_for_building_distro
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1073838&highlight=build%20distro
- http://minez-inspirate.blogspot.com/2009/04/create-distro-livecd-ubuntu-with-ubuntu.html
- http://lxer.com/module/newswire/view/162978/index.html

I hope this is of help.

edit: Also, check out [this possible duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174331/how-do-i-configure-the-live-usb-to-install-additional-packages).